# Bootstrap pull-right overlapping div width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried to use `.well` and `.clearfix`, but it doesn't work.
I added a border to the div, so you can see what's happening.
[image]

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="login">
        <div class="row">
            <div align="center">
                <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="">
                    <input class="form-control span6" type="text">
                    <input class="form-control span6" type="password">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login pull-right">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
#login
{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: You're not following the bootstrap docs.  Take a look at them again http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

Comment: you're combining stuff from 2.x and 3 versions of bootstrap but neither look correct. There is no center class AFIK

Comment: Besides looking at the docs for the correct version you're using, if you are using 3, this is a very comprehensive tutorial: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with `.clearfix`, since you have to reset floats after using `.pull-right` on your button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-login pull-right">Login</button>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I pulled unnecessary markup out too, in this example: **http://www.bootply.com/XmjTuujzme**

-- That being said, you are indeed mixing some BS22 and BS3 code, which will only cause problems. Best to adopt BS3 entirely...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you but first what I would do is take the `<div class="row">` and put it inside the form.

if that is not working then try to replace the btn-login to btn-primery or something like that because you maybe have a problem with this class.